# Find the text between two Characters

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match-all, explode

I want to find the text between two characters

```
$var ='J111 king Jadv oops J123 php';
```

In above variable i get only the letter start from J.

i need following output,

Starting J values as

```
Array ( [0] =>J111 [1] => Jadv [2] => J123)
```

and balance values as,

```
Array ( [0] =>king [1] => oops [2] => php)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with :

```
$var ='J111 king Jadv oops J123 php';

//get all the words in array
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $var);

//match all the words starting with letter J
preg_match_all('(J[^\s]+)', $var, $matches);

//words with matching letter
$words_with_letter = $matches[0];

//words without matching letter
$words_without_letter = array_values(array_diff($words,$words_with_letter));
```

Hope this helps for you  :)

Answer (score 1):

Regex to get all the J values (live demo: http://regexr.com?306v4 )

```
/(J[^\s]+)/g
```

Currently working on the other one.